# Creating a dictionary with word frequency percentages in a descending order

Tags: python, word-frequency

I have created a dictionary showing word frequencies as values. First of all I need to convert these frequencies to percentages. The total number of the words is 150482. Second, I need to put this dictionary in descending order (based on values which are frequencies for words as keys) and compare it against another dictionary which has frequent words in it. Any idea how to do this two things: namely changing the values in percentages and putting them in descending order in one dicitonary (this last part if needed for comparison only) and second, comparing this dictionary against the dictionary of the frequent words. 
Here is the first dictionary I need to change the values to percentage.

```
di=dict()
with open('content.txt',encoding='utf8') as newtext:
    for line in newtext:
        line=line.rstrip()
        words=line.split()
        for word in words:
            di[word]=di.get(word,0)+1
```

The goal is to find out what percentage of frequent words in the frequent words dictionary occur in the di (which shows the frequency of words in a text file). The first dictionary is like {the:TRUE}. In other words, no values. Just keys are words in need to find their occurrence with their associated frequency percentage in the file text.

Comment: `collections.Counter` may be a good option for you https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: You might also need `OrderedDict()` instead of normal `dict`.

Answer (score 4):

A good start is using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('content.txt',encoding='utf8') as newtext:
    c = Counter(word for line in newtext for word in line.rstrip().split())

by_count = c.most_common()  # e.g. [('the', 123), ('a', 83), ...]
```

You can then manipulate that to get frequencies:

```
total = sum(c.values())
by_freq = [(k, v/total) for k, v in by_count]
# or in Python2:
# by_freq = [(k, float(v)/total) for k, v in by_count]
```

Comment: What exactly ends up an empty dict?

Answer (score 0):

This should work and print the percentage dictionary as you expected.

```
from collections import Counter
percentage_dict = {}
with open('content.txt',encoding='utf8') as newtext:
    c = Counter(word for line in newtext for word in line.rstrip().split())
total_words = sum([j for j in dict(c).values()])
for i, j in dict(c).items():
    percentage_dict[i] = (j/total_words)*100
print(sorted(percentage_dict.items(), reverse=True))
```

Comment: I'm just getting the words with no frequencies at all. Just words, some repeated several times in different places.

Comment: This worked exactly as expected for me. Can you please post the output you got.